# PHP: var_dump spitting out wrong format from json_decode

Tags: php, json, var-dump

My code:

```
$json_data = file_get_contents($json_url,0,null,null);  
$json_output = json_decode($json_data); 
var_dump($json_output);
```

This is what var_dump spits out in one big line, not formatted at all:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (1) { ["timetableresult"]=> object(stdClass)#2 (1) { ["ttitem"]=> array(17) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#3 (1) { ["segment"]=> array(8) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#4 (3) { ["segmentid"]=> object(stdClass)#5 (2) { ["mot"]=> object(stdClass)#6 (3) { ["@displaytype"]=> string(1) "G" ["@type"]=> string(1) "G" ["#text"]=> string(5) "GÃ¥ng" } ["distance"]=> int(1008) } ["departure"]=> object(stdClass)#7 (2)... etc.etc.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have xdebug installed? It will add a lot of extra info - as well as formating to your var_debug. Try using print_r instead of var_dump)

Comment: Look in the source, or do: `echo "<pre>".var_dump( json_output )."</pre>";`

Comment: print_r gets the result: "stdClass Object ( [timetableresult] => stdClass Object ( [ttitem] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [segment] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [segmentid] => stdClass Object ( [mot] => stdClass Object ( [@displaytype] => G [@type] => G [#text]... etc.etc". Still in one big line though.

Comment: John your result gave the following: "string(11) "json_output""

Comment: HTML does not render linebreaks or whitespace. Check the page's source.

Comment: Checked source and indeed looks like it should, anyone know how to get this working via HTML?

Comment: @John : echo "<pre>"; var_dump($json_output); echo "</pre>"; worked!

Answer (score 6):

`var_dump` prints newlines. Browsers do not render newlines.

Try `echo "<pre>"; var_dump($json_output); echo "</pre>";`

Comment: And there is the answer :) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You're doing a var dump, to access the properties you would do something like this:
$seg_id = $json_output->timetableresult->ttitem->segment[0]->segmentid;
I didn't actually look closely at the structure of your json, but that is approximately what you'll want.

Or... 
If you do this
foreach($json_output->timetableresult->ttitem as $item) {
   var_dump($item);
}

You'll begin to see how to access all the parts you want.

Comment: You are correct! However, I have 9000 lines to go through (headache!)! Anyway I got a correct answer! :)

Comment: I see, I didn't understand the problem was purely formatting the display, I should have paid more attention!